# Hadoop: why secondary namenode should be running all the time

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to understand what is the point of having hadoop secondary namenode running all the time. As far as I know it makes periodic (once per hour by default) merges of fsimage and editfiles.

Why it is a daemon, not a utility run periodically (let's say, as a cron job)?

Answer (score 0):

The interval of the checkpoint is not only dependent on time. It depends on some other factors also. Depending on that, the checkpoint frequency may vary.

**dfs.namenode.checkpoint.txns** - The Secondary NameNode or CheckpointNode will create a checkpoint of the namespace every 'dfs.namenode.checkpoint.txns' transactions, regardless of whether 'dfs.namenode.checkpoint.period' has expired.

**dfs.namenode.checkpoint.period** - The number of seconds between two periodic checkpoints.

Among the above properties, the transactions count may cross the limit at any time. It can happen in few minutes also. Other than this, the admin can manually trigger the checkpointing process. So with all these requirements, the secondary namenode should be always up. If it just runs periodically, it won't serve its purpose properly.

Answer (score 0):

Best explanation of what secondary namenode is really meant for:
http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/secondary-namenode---what-it-really-do/

> Secondary Namenode (SNN) is one of the poorly named component in Hadoop. By its name, it gives a sense that its a backup for the Namenode (NN). But in reality its not.

Secondary Namenode's whole purpose is to have a checkpoint of Namenode in HDFS, so that it can save the latest possible image of Namenode in events of Namenode crash/failure (Its not the replacement for the Namenode) and then use this checkpoint to bring namenode up again. That is why SNN should be running all the time and have almost similar configuration as that of NN.

Maybe this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEqQMLSXQlY) would explain it better!

Answer (score -1):

Good question, the reason for this behaviour is that it can take over the role from the primary namenode and become the primary. This happens during the failover either caused by an outage or maintenance. If it was just a cron job it would add significant delay to the failover procedure.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Secondary_NameNode